# Broadcom BCM4312 Wireless Modem UNCLAIMED After Installing Updates

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, pci

About a month ago, Ubuntu stopped recognizing my wireless adapter. Here is the output of the wireless-info script:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15494675/

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
```

Here is `lspci -vnn | grep 14e4`:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]:
Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

According to http://linuxwireless.org, this model is supported. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

It said that I already had the latest version. Until the other day, I could connect by booting to Ubuntu release 77 instead of 79, but now that also doesn't work. I've always been able to connect if I boot to Windows 7.

I'm stumped, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

According to your wireless script output, the `b43` driver is blacklisted by `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

```
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

You need to remove it by running

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

That package was wrongly installed. Then you can start `b43` by

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

or reboot.

Comment: If @Pilot6 's answer has been helpful, please accept it. http://askubuntu.com/tour